# Equations and finite number of roots

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following equation:

$$\vartheta(\beta)=g(\beta)+\theta(\beta),$$

where $\beta$ is a real variable. I know that the function $\vartheta(\beta)$ has only $m$ real  solutions. Then $g(\beta)+\theta(\beta)=0$ has also the same $m$ solutions. Hence, $g(\beta)=-\theta(\beta)$ has also the same $m$ solutions.

My question is: Is this approach correct.

Comment: Yes, of course (though one would speak of solutions rather than roots in the latter case)

Comment: Comment removed. (@Hagen Von Eitzen: oups, and sorry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you want to make it more formal, you can say:

Let $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots r_m$ be distinct numbers such that $\vartheta(r_k) = 0$. Now we have:

$$ \vartheta(\beta) = g(\beta) + \theta(\beta)$$

Now let $\beta = r_k$ (for suitable k, of course). Then:

$$ \vartheta(r_k) = g(r_k) + \theta(r_k) $$
$$ 0 = g(r_k) + \theta(r_k) $$

and:

$$ -g(r_k) = \theta(r_k) $$

This is true for any integer $k$ from $1$ to $m$. Hence, the above equations have the same number of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\vartheta(\beta)=g(\beta)+\theta(\beta)$ for all $\beta$. Since $$\vartheta(\beta)=0\iff g(\beta)+\theta(\beta)=0\iff g(\beta)=-\theta(\beta),$$ the equations $\vartheta(\beta)=0$ and $g(\beta)=-\theta(\beta)$ have the same solutions.